# jqGrid autowith on page resize with hideable menu

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I had a page with a vertical menu hideable. In the same page I had a jqgrid with the "autowidth:true" parameter. 
When I load the page, the menu it's visible, but if I hide the menu, the width of my jqgrid remains with the same size. 
How I can change the width of jqgrid when menu is hide and again when it's visible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call [setGridWidth](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3amethods) method directly after you hide or show the "vertical menu". It allows you to resize the width of of all columns of the grid additionally to the width of the grid itself.